# Glassfish 3.1.2 and Eclipse

Tags: glassfish

I just downloaded the Glassfish version 3.1.2, this is not yet an official release.
I need this version because my web application is using websockets.
The problem I have now is with the Glassfish plugin for eclipse, he is not recognizing the new Glassfish Version.
With the Glassfish Version 3.1.1 in Eclipse everything works fine.
I am using Oracle Glassfish Server Tools (Eclipse plugin ) version 2.0.0.20111104904 from Oracle(last version I could download).
If I try to add a new Server Runtime Environment in Eclipse for the Glassfish 3.1.2 I get the error:
There is no valid GlassFish installation in the specified directory...
I need everything to be able to debug my web application in Eclipse.

Anyone know what the plugin is checking ?
There is any change to trick the plugin so will run with Glashfish 3.1.2 too ?

Comment: Unless there is an obvious error that you make (like not specify the directory exactly), then I really doubt this is possible.

Answer (score 18):

Use the plugin from here (for Indigo): http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/indigo/

The plugin for Helios does not support 3.1.2.

If you have to live with the bits the are blessed by Oracle or keep using Helios, then you can try the following trick:

> create a couple files....
>
> ${glassfish.rootdirectory}/modules/jsf-impl.jar and
>   ${glassfish.rootdirectory}/modules/jstl-impl.jar
>
> These files were renamed between 3.1.1 and 3.1.2...
>
> You may be able to get the 3.1.2 to mascarade as 3.1.1 by just
>   creating empty files with the above names.  If that doesn't do it,
>   make copies of the following files should do it.
>
> The new name for jstl-impl.jar is
>   gf312/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar
>
> The new name for jsf-impl.jar is
>   gf312/glassfish/modules/javax.faces.jar.

Comment: Any idea why Indigo version of the plugin is not in Eclipse Marketplace? Does that indicate the project to be dead, unofficial or whatever? http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/ suggests that the plugin was last updated in December 2009

Comment: if you go in the eclipse indigo and start the eclipse marketplace, then type glassfish and then press find you will find out the Glassfish Java EE Application Server Plugin for Eclipse, it is possible that you need a Eclipse Indigo EE Edition. The second option is the GlassFish Tools Bundle for Eclipse, but I am using the first option because it is up to date. The GlassFish Tools Bundle for Eclipse you can install for Eclipse Indigo too.

Answer (score 6):

If you are on Helios, you can try the following:

- uninstall the Glassfish 3.1.1 plugin (and all associated runtimes and servers).
- go to "Install new software" and type in (for the URL): http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/indigo

Though the plugin says indigo, it is also working for me in Helios. And it gives options for both Glassfish 3.1.1 and 3.1.2 servers (pre and post name changes).

Note that it downloads Glassfish itself, and installs an internal server. You can delete that one, and install your own server ("New server...") if you have an existing server you want to work with (as I did).

HTH.