# Add GlassFish 3.1.2 Runtime to Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, runtime, glassfish-3, eclipse-juno

I've recently installed Juno EE Edition and am trying to get my Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (open source edition) server runtime set up.

I installed Glassfish separately via the zip file.  My directory looks like:

```
C:\Servers\glassfish3112\glassfish
```

In Eclipse, I installed the "Glassfish Java EE Application Server Plugin for Eclipse" which also installed "Oracle Glassfish Server Tools".  These are the jars/directories that were added to my plugins directory:

- oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish_3.2.3.201106220649.jar
- oracle.eclipse.tools.doc.javaee6_1.0.0.201106220649
- oracle.eclipse.tools.doc.javaee5_1.0.0.201106220649
- org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.db.generic_1.0.0.v201107221520.jar (which contains)

  - oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish_4.2.1.201207240841.jar
  - oracle.eclipse.runtime.glassfish3122_3.1.2.201207240841.jar

I then went into my Preferences | Server | Runtim Environments to add my Glassfish server.  When I choose the above path, I get the error message *There is no valid GlassFish installlation in the specified directory.  Click the Install Server button to download and install to that directory.*

I found this StackOverflow question [Glassfish 3.1.2 and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001120/glassfish-3-1-2-and-eclipse) which indicates that the Marketplace plugin does not work with GF 3.1.2 and gives this link to get the Juno version: http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/indigo/plugins/

The latest runtime and tools jars on that site are the ones included in the org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.db.generic_1.0.0.v201107221520.jar.

Can somebody explain to me what I've done wrong and how to get my runtime set up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the Juno plugin version here:
http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/juno/

This includes support for GlassFish 3.1.2.2.

Best,
TM

PS. Don't forget to uninstall all other Glassfish plugins before installing this one.

Comment: I deleted my Juno install to make sure I was starting clean and downloaded the plugin you linked to and get the same error.  If I change the JRE from ``Default JRE`` to ``re6``, I get ``Missing classpath entry C:\Servers\glassfish3112\glassfish\modules\jsf-api.jar``.

This was a Glassfish bug (http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS-350) that was apparently fixed in ``oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish_4.2.1.201112152311.jar``. The Juno plugin installed ``oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish_5.0.1.201207240829.jar``, so the fix should be in there.

Comment: So, didn't change anything, but tried one more time and this time it worked.  Very confusing.

Comment: That URL does no longer exist.

Comment: Yes, the official Eclipse plugin has been updated for GF 3.1.2. You can get it from the market now.